# NavController.handleDeepLink() not working

Tags: android, deep-linking, navigation-architecture

I'm trying to handle a deep-link with in the app using:-

```
findNavigationController.handleDeepLink(intent)
```

which is not navigating to any page.

here is how I created the intent:-

```
val deepLinkIntent = Intent()
val deeplink = "https://myapp.com/myscreen"
deepLinkIntent.data = Uri.parse(deeplink)
findNavigationController.handleDeepLink(deepLinkIntent) // this returning false
```

Am I doing correctly? If not what's the correct way of handling in-app deeplinks (which I required to handle for some internal promotion cards)?